# Edit Text Outside of Evernote (Mac)

Tags: macos, evernote

Evernote is fine, but its text editor is strange and not good for storing code snippets. The fact that is allows HTML but can only manipulate a subset of HTML is a bit frustrating.

Is there any way to edit Evernote snippets outside of Evernote?

**Note:** To clarify, I mean: is there any way, using Evernote, to edit the snippets in an external editor?

Answer (score 2):

I think we may need a little bit more Clarity here on your question...

> Evernote is fine, but its text editor
>   is strange and not good for storing
>   code snippets. The fact that is allows
>   HTML but can only manipulate a subset
>   of HTML is a bit frustrating.
>
> Is there any way to edit Evernote
>   snippets outside of Evernote?

My first read thru suggests this:

> Copy and Paste the Evernote text into
>   TextEdit, or another editor of your
>   choice.  Clean it up, modify it to
>   your pleasure...  Then Copy & Paste it
>   back into Evernote.

But I maybe misunderstanding your question...  Do you mean to edit the Evernote data without using Evernote?  The data is stored in ~\Library\Application Support\Evernote

The Evernote.sql file is presumably the SQL database that stores the tags, sync information, etc...

The Content folder is broken up into individual folders, in my case, marked PXX where XX is a number...  Inside each folder is an filename.ENML, filename.html, & thumbnail files.

The ENML appears to be an XML file with the contents of the note.  The content.html appears to be a straight HTML file of the content, and the thumbnail files are thumbnail views...

I modified the XML file, and the evernote client did not see the changes...  So I presume you can modify the data, but without reverse engineering the database, you can't force the client to sync the changed data....

Comment: Hi and thanks, you understood the question perfectly, but I was hoping for a way to do it without cutting and pasting. FileZilla, for instance, has an "edit" button and it detects when you're done.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, your first read through was what I was thinking, but the solution is less-than-elegant. But yeah, I just want a way to use an external editor with Everynote.

Answer (score 2):

you could try QuickCursor http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/quickcursor I did not use it myself, but they claim

> QuickCursor brings your favorite text
>   editor* to any app with a global
>   keyboard shortcut. ... *QuickCursor
>   works with BBEdit, Espresso, MacVim,
>   Smultron, SubEthaEdit, TextMate,
>   TextWrangler, and WriteRoom.

Comment: The method is OK but not perfect. Since you could only edit notes as plain text. All the style information would lose.

Comment: Whoah! I'm trying this out now (never noticed your answer in July of 2011) and it works pretty well so far. Amazing, thank you!

Comment: QuickCursor is okay, but it's a real hack and it shows through in so many ways. I mean using it with Evernote. Quickcursor is fine.

Comment: And now out of business